# in app purchasing submission process iphone

Tags: iphone, submit, in-app-purchase

I am trying to submit my first iPhone app that has in-app purchasing features. Needless to say, I have been banging my head against the wall for a while. I have read through several tutorials, such as: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ and  http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/ but it seems these are outdated? For instance, I can't find where the developer is to reject the submission on iTunes connect.

Additionally, I am submitting the app the in-app purchase features included in the bundle(I don't have them stored on the server- I just want to unlock the code when the user purchases the feature). What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the information in the linked tutorials is in fact outdated: I could create in app items in iTunes connect without having to submit (and reject) a binary first. Just be sure NOT to submit your items for review while you are testing. Also changes to the items (e.g. price tier) have been processed almost immediately and I did not had to wait 24 hours.

To unlock your feature, you may use storing and retrieving the purchased status in `NSUserDefaults` . But this could easily be tempered with by users with jailbreak or acces to the apps folder. Have a look at http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-ios-keychain-wrapper-for-easily-securing-user-data-for-your-app/ . This offers a simple way to store data in the keychain. Still this will not prevent someone to 'hack' your app and enable the purchased feature without actual purchase, but it's not that easy...

Comment: I also have a free app with in app purchase. So your app must not be a paid one, but the contract for paid app must be in effect. Check the contracts section in iTunes connect to activate that contract

Comment: I think this might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In-App Purchase development is definitely a pain point in iOS development - their sandboxing model for this is ridiculous.

Needless to say - the articles you're reading are still up to date. The developer reject is definitely the way to go (I think can do from within the binary details). One thing to remember is that you need to have accepted the appropriate contracts and tax schedules also - if you haven't then the store "just doesn't work".

One thing that caught me: when you submit your final version of the app - make sure you tick the in-app purchases to be included; else the in-app purchases won't be reviewed (and accepted)!

Update: Although it's pretty long... you may want to flick through this: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Explains how to developer reject etc.

Comment: I was just looking over that. One problem I am having is that I don't have the "Manage In-App Purchases" button in my iTunes connect for my application. Apple says that I need to have a paid application on iTunes connect or else this button won't appear. The problem is, I don't want to have a paid app. Its free with in-app purchasing...